# GTM dataLayer push on link click - race condition?

Tags: events, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm setting up some events that is push to GTM with dataLayer.push. These events happen at the click of a link which naturally directs to a new page. I'm worried about race conditions and need some input on this.

**The way I have it set up is as follows:**

- User clicks a link
- @click runs a method that pushes to the dataLayer. There is no preventDefault, callbacks or anything like that on this method.
- GTM receives the event and sends it to GA with "transport beacon" set.

The way I understand it, the transport beacon method is useful for sending events and not have to worry about race conditions when loading a new page. However - the transport beacon is used by GTM and not by me when pushing to the dataLayer, so is there not still a possibility that GTM does not have time to process the event before the next page load and thus the event will never be sent to GA?

In my testing, the events always work as intended, still I am unsure that this is necessarily the case and not just something that I happen to experience.

Could anyone shed some light on this?